# About definition of improper integral.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am reading "Introduction to Analysis" by Kunihiko Kodaira(in Japanese).
In this book, the author wrote as follows:

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $(a, b)$.
> If $\lim_{t\to b-0, s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx$ exists, we define
> $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx := \lim_{t\to b-0, s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx.$$
> This means for any positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that if $b-\delta(\epsilon)<t<b, a<s<a+\delta(\epsilon)$, then
> $$|\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx - \int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx| < \epsilon.$$
> If $c$ is a real number such that $a < c < b$, then $$\int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx = \int_{s}^{c} f(x) dx + \int_{c}^{t} f(x) dx,$$ so $$\lim_{t\to b-0, s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx=\lim_{s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{c} f(x) dx+\lim_{t\to b-0}\int_{c}^{t} f(x) dx,$$
> therefore, we can write $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=\lim_{s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{c} f(x) dx+\lim_{t\to b-0}\int_{c}^{t} f(x) dx.$$

I cannot prove that if $\lim_{t\to b-0, s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx$ exists, then both $\lim_{s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{c} f(x) dx$ and $\lim_{t\to b-0}\int_{c}^{t} f(x) dx$ exist and the following equality holds:
$$\lim_{t\to b-0, s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx=\lim_{s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{c} f(x) dx+\lim_{t\to b-0}\int_{c}^{t} f(x) dx.$$

---

I proved the above fact. Is my proof OK?

Comment: "I cannot prove..." followed by "I proved the above fact". What ??

Answer (score 1):

> Lemma 1:
> Let $F(x)$ be a function on $(a, b)$.
> If $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(x_n)$ exists for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n \in (a, b)$ for any $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=b$, then $\lim_{x\to b-0} F(x)$ exists.

> Proof:
> Let $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\}$ be arbitrary two sequences on $(a, b)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = b$.
> Let $\{z_n\}$ be a sequence such that $z_{2 n} = x_n$ and $z_{2 n + 1} = y_n$.
> Obviously $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n = b$ and $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\}$ are subsequences of $\{z_n\}$.
> So, $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(x_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} F(z_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} F(y_n) =: \alpha$.
> Assume that $\lim_{x\to b-0} F(x) = \alpha$ does not hold.
> Then, there exists $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that the following statement holds:
> For any $\delta >0$, there exists $x$ such that $b-\delta < x < b$ and $|F(x) - \alpha| \geq \epsilon_0$.
> So, for any $n$, there exists $x_n$ such that $b-\frac{1}{n} < x_n < b$ and $|F(x_n) - \alpha| \geq \epsilon_0$.
> $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence on $(a, b)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = b$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(x_n) \neq \alpha$.
> This is a contradiction.

> Lemma 2:
> Let $F(x)$ be a function on $(a, b)$.
> If the following statement holds, then $\lim_{x\to b-0} F(x) \in \mathbb{R}$:
> For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $b-\delta < x < b$ and $b-\delta < y < b$, then $|F(x) - F(y)| < \epsilon$.

> Proof:
> Let $\{x_n\}$ be any sequence on $(a, b)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = b$.
> For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that if $n > N$, then $b-\epsilon < x_n < b$.
> So, if $m, n > N$, then $b-\epsilon < x_n < b, b-\epsilon < y_n < b$.
> So, if $m, n > N$, then $|F(x_m) - F(x_n)| < \epsilon$.
> By Cauchy's criterion for convergence, the sequence $\{F(x_n)\}$ converges.
> By Lemma 1, $\lim_{x\to b-0} F(x) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now I prove the following statement:

> If $\lim_{t\to b-0, s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx$ exists, then both $\lim_{s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{c} f(x) dx$ and $\lim_{t\to b-0}\int_{c}^{t} f(x) dx$ exist and the following equality holds:
> $$\lim_{t\to b-0, s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx=\lim_{s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{c} f(x) dx+\lim_{t\to b-0}\int_{c}^{t} f(x) dx.$$

> Proof:
> Let $\lim_{t\to b-0, s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx = S$.
> Then, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $a < s < a+\delta$ and $b-\delta < t < b$, then $|\int_{s}^{t} f(x) dx - S| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
> Let $c$ be a real number such that $a < c < b$.
> Let $F(x) := \int_{c}^{x} f(t) dt$ for $x \in (a, b)$.
> For any $t_1, t_2, s$ such that $t_1, t_2 \in (b-\delta, b)$ and $s \in (a, a+\delta)$, $|F(t_1) - F(t_2)| = |\int_{s}^{t_1} f(t) dt - \int_{s}^{t_2} f(t) dt| \leq |\int_{s}^{t_1} f(t) dt -S| + |\int_{s}^{t_2} f(t) dt -S| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$.
> By Lemma 2, $\lim_{x\to b-0} F(x) =: S_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.
> By similar argument, $\lim_{x\to a+0} \int_{x}^{c} f(t) dt =: S_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.
> It is easy to prove that $S = S_1 + S_2.$

Comment: Although I did not read everything thoroughly, I see that you are grasping the key idea (to invoke the Cauchy criteria to prove the convergence of one-sided limits) of the proof. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, I would like to mention that it follows from a more general claim:

> **Lemma.** Let $g, h:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be functions. Then the followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $ \displaystyle\lim_{\substack{t\to b-0\\s\to a+0}} (g(s)+h(t)) $ converges.
> 2. Both $ \displaystyle\lim_{s\to a+0} g(s) $ and $ \displaystyle\lim_{t\to b-0} h(t) $ converge.
>
> Moreover, in such case, we have
> $$ \lim_{\substack{t\to b-0\\s\to a+0}} (g(s)+h(t)) = \lim_{s\to a+0} g(s) + \lim_{t\to b-0} h(t). $$

Once this lemma is established, we may fix $c \in (a, b)$ and apply this lemma to

$$ g(s) = \int_{s}^{c} f(u) \, \mathrm{d}u \qquad\text{and}\qquad h(t) = \int_{c}^{t} f(u) \, \mathrm{d}u. $$

As for the proof of the lemma, you see that the key idea is no different from your solution:

---

*Proof of Lemma.* $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ : Write $L$ for the value of $\lim_{\substack{t\to b-0\\s\to a+0}} (g(s)+h(t))$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$$ \left| g(s) + h(t) - L \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \qquad\text{whenever}\qquad s \in (a, a+\delta) \quad \text{and} \quad t \in(b-\delta, b).$$

Now fix $s_0 \in (a, a+\delta)$ and $t_0 \in (b-\delta, b)$. Then for any $s, s' \in (a, a+\delta)$, we have

\begin{align*}
\left| g(s) - g(s') \right|
&= \left| (g(s) + h(t_0) - L) - (g(s) + h(t_0) - L) \right| \\
&\leq \left| g(s) + h(t_0) - L \right| + \left| g(s) + h(t_0) - L \right| \\
&< \epsilon,
\end{align*}

and likewise, for any $t, t' \in (b-\delta, b)$,

\begin{align*}
\left| h(t) - h(t') \right|
&= \left| (g(s_0) + h(t) - L) - (g(s_0) + h(t') - L) \right| \\
&\leq \left| g(s_0) + h(t) - L \right| + \left| g(s_0) + h(t') - L \right| \\
&< \epsilon.
\end{align*}

This proves that $g(s)$ is Cauchy as $s \to a+0$ and $h(t)$ is Cauchy as $t \to b-0$. Therefore both $\lim_{s\to a+0} g(s)$ and $\lim_{t\to b-0} h(t)$ converge by the Cauchy criterion.

$(2)\Rightarrow(1)$ : Write $\alpha = \lim_{s \to a+0} g(s)$ and $\beta = \lim_{t \to b-0} h(t)$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

- $\left| g(s) - \alpha \right| < \epsilon/2$ whenever $s \in (a, a+\delta)$, and
- $\left| h(t) - \beta \right| < \epsilon/2$ whenever $t \in (b-\delta, b)$.

Then it follows that

$$ \left| (g(s) + h(t)) - (\alpha + \beta) \right| \leq \left| g(s) - \alpha \right| + \left| h(t) - \beta \right| < \epsilon $$

whenever $s \in (a, a+\delta)$ and $t \in (b-\delta, b)$, and therefore $\text{(1)}$ is proved. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

If two limits exist, the the limit of the sum exists and is the sum of the limits. *The converse is not true*.